# How can I update tom-select to reflect changes in an underlying HTML select element?

Tags: javascript, tom-select

I have an html select at which tom-select is initialized. At some user action a selection of the html select is changed from code - an option element is added and the value of a select is set. I cannot force the tom-select to reflect that state.

I tried to use different combinations of API calls: `sync`, `clear` + `addItem`, `setValue` but didn't manage to get the result I want.
On the other hand, if the raw select has the option and value set before TomSelect is created it works as I would like - the label from the selected option is also selected and visible in TomSelect. Calling `destroy` clear the HTML options so re-creating is not straightforward.

Here is a reproducible sample - https://codepen.io/BDomzalski/pen/abRXoRY

Comment: Can you add some reproducible code?

Comment: Please refer to the following URL:
https://tom-select.js.org/examples/api/

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause of the issue in the examplary code - I used `label` property of the `HTMLOptionElement` while TomSelect uses `textContent`.

My problem from the real code was different - it was because of non-default value of `labelField` setting. Reported an [issue](https://github.com/orchidjs/tom-select/issues/598).